# What does からと mean in this passage

Tags: grammar

The passage is as follows

> 「ちょうどクラスの半分が参加しているみたいですね」
>
> 「え、そんなに？」
>
> 先ずはマユリさん**からと**練習していた為、気にしていなかったのか、私に言われ指さし確認する。

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

This と is a quotative particle, but the related verb is omitted.

> 先ずはマユリさんからと練習していた為

is:

> 「先ずはマユリさんから」と（思って）練習していた為
>   (He/she) was practicing thinking "I'll start with Mayuri", so...

Related:

- [verb+ようにと、 or verb+かと、](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21680/5010)
- [What does にと do?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16000/5010)

Answer (score 0):

You will know the meaning of "と"(with).
In this sentence からと means 'with' too.

"から" means 'from', but why do we use 'from' when we are 'practicing with' someone? I think it's used because there is "先ずは"(At first,).